# Web Services - WSDL Push API

Tags: web-services, wsdl, push, datastore

Any help much appreciated. I am looking for suggestions for an architecture for the following scenario.

I am looking to setup a server/database to store a high frequency data set. The source data provider has made the following requirements for a destination system to be able to subscribe to the Push service.

- Must have a valid "HTTPS" URL.
- Web Services enabled to handle WSDL form data.
- SSL enabled

I am working from a blank slate, and I am looking for suggestions for best language/server/datastore combination.

Many thanks

PJ

Comment: Too vague I think.What languages/DBs do you know?

Comment: I agree my question is vague, but I wanted to invite any 'best of breed' solutions that people have used. If I had to develop this immediately I would return to what i know Java/Oracle. But as this project is non commercial I am open to learning new technologies.